# Is it okay to add a link to only one tab in tab bar?

Tags: mobile, ios, tab-bar

I am working on a scanning app that has two possible workflows.  The mock up below is the scan screen for one of those workflows.  Users can switch tabs to go home, see previous scans, and access settings.  They can also use the "Scan Options" link in the upper right to switch workflows.

My question: I would like to only include the Scan Options link on the "Scan" tab, as that is where users will be the majority of the time.  Is it a bad practice if the link isn't available from the other tabs as well, or would it be okay to only have it on the scan tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only having it on the "scan" tab sounds perfectly acceptable & is the way most tab-separated apps work, esp in [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html).
Each tab has a distinct associated view for a different mode or sub-task.

If the "Scan Options" functionality only makes sense to use inside the "scan" tab then put it there & nowhere else. That said, if you wanted to have a dedicated one-touch "Scan Now!" button available from any tab, that'd be a different story...

I can't think of how it could be useful w/"previous scans" anyway - those settings are already fixed (right? Or is that the selling point - you can retroactively change settings on previously scanned items? ...Cuz that'd be neat :) ).

Comment: Nope, you're right, previous scans is static data simply used for reference.  Thanks for your input - much appreciated!